# How to reference and ship an external / third-party .NET DLL within a solution under version control at Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, version-control, .net-assembly, projects-and-solutions

## Fast question

How to correctly add a reference to an external / third-party .NET DLL (which is not a NuGet package and not in GAC) and force it to be shipped as a part of solution (which is under version control) in Visual Studio?

## Long story

I have a Visual Studio 2013 solution, which contains a couple of .NET projects. The solution is under source control. There is a lot of installed NuGet packages that are used by the projects, of course. But one of the projects need to reference an external / third-party .NET DLL that is not available as a NuGet package and doesn't reside in GAC. If I just add a reference to that DLL in the project, it will work fine for the moment. But after I check-in a changeset with such modification, anyone who will get the latest version of the solution will encounter a problem with building it, because the one does not have the referenced .NET DLL on his machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two  possible solutions  to your problem

1. You can add the dll on the  TFS. Create a folder  under your solution called lib, for example and put your dll in there. Then reference the dll from that folder. When you check the changes in , include the  lib folder with the dll. Once someone else will get latest, they will get both your changes and the new dll. Do note that  dlls referenced under the solution's folder use a relative path, so anyone else who has that folder  and  the dll in the solution's folder won't need to do anything else
2. Make a nuget package with that dll and host it on your  very own nuget feed.  You can  get a feed  and host it on iis on a dedicated machine or you can use a network share :). Nuget  works with  "folder sources" too. The Nuget feed is just a fancy ui over a  folder repository. This adds the advantage taht you won't have dlls under source control

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for a both options! I will look into the first for this time, but will take into account a possibility of the second option in future. If I create a folder under a solution's folder and copy external DLLs there, source control module does not detect all these actions as a pending change to my solution. Would you kindly explain more detailed, how do I make source control to detect a creation of "lib" folder, which contains needed external .NET DLLs?

Comment: Unfortunateley visual studio won't detect that pending change automatically however this can be done easily from the SourceControl Expolorer. Navigate to your Project/Branch/Solution folder right click on it and  select "Add Items to Folder...". A wizard pops up showing you a list of available folders.  Select your  Lib folder and hit next. Initially TFS will ignore dlls, but you can find them in the Exceuded items tab. Click on the excluded tab, include them and hit finish. Then the dll will appeaar in your pending changes and can be checked in.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new folder in the project where the dll is required then reference the dll in the project from there and then chekck-in the dll.
When the other users will get latest project/solution they will get this dll automatically and they will not get problem in building.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider checking-in the external DLL in the source control as well. Create an "Externals" folder within the project folder and place external DLLs there. Use this path to reference the external DLL. This should work with other developers as well as when they checkout they will have the DLL and proper relative path in csproj.